# Glass material looks different in final render and cycles viewport, manta flow. I have transparent glass turned on

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, mantaflow

Here is the viewport in cycles renderer.

[image: cycles viewport]

And here is my final render.

[image: final render]

Why is there a difference?

Comment: have you checked if you had another sphere that you've made invisible for render?

Comment: The icosphere emitter is hidden in viewport but how do I make it hidden in render? That might be why

Comment: take a look at your Outliner, the camera icon should be greyed, if you can't see it, click on the funnel icon on the top of the Outliner window in order to display the option

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First, try denoising. It appears that your render hasn't been denoised. If you don't know how to do that, go under render properties, sampling, denoising, and then check off render, but not the viewport.

Comment: As I understand it, the issue is about the glass not being transparent in the final render. De-noising will not fix it.